# Light switches are not working, all outlets are

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I woke up this morning and realized that none of the light switches in my home are working, however all outlets are still working. I checked the breaker and nothing was tripped, then I went ahead and reset the breaker just to insure that that was not the problem.

The only other information I have to offer is that I changed a three-way switch in my home yesterday however, it worked throughout the rest of the day.

Comment: So every switch in the house isn't working?  Check the wiring on the switch you replaced.

Comment: Is the switch you replaced in the on or off position? did you mi up a wire and all the lights are now switched by that switch?

Comment: I checked the wiring and all the wires are still connected and tight. The switch is in the on and i have checked other lights and they still currently do not work. I also tried capping and bypassing that switch and the other switches still do not work.

Comment: Do you only have 1 breaker for all the lights in your home? I have seen this on older homes but it is rare. Are the lights on a even number breaker and the odd on a odd breaker?

Comment: There is only one breaker and it is a 1956 home. The lights are on an even breaker

Comment: Can you post a photo of your breaker box please?

Comment: What is the brand of your electrical panel? Are your 240 V appliances working? If any one 240 V appliance is working properly, then you have not lost one leg entirely. Possibly the lighting breaker is malfunctioning. Do you have a non contact voltage tester?